# zend_db obtain "select ..., (select ...) as x from ... "

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I have a query that i can't build with Zend_Db_Select

```
SELECT `f`.*,          
        (SELECT Sum(x) AS `y`
        FROM   z AS pf
        WHERE  pf.q_id = f.id) AS w
FROM  f ...
WHERE ...
GROUP  BY `f`.`id`
```

so at the moment i'm running it manually `$db->fetchAll($sql)`.

How do i obtain

```
select f.* , (select ...) as `something` from ...
```

I was thinking using `->column('f.*, (select...)')` but it didn't work,

it could work maybe with a left join if i do (select ..., id) and then join on that id, but i wanted to obtain THIS very sql query. Is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the JOIN.  You might get better performance as sub selects are usually hard for the database to optimize.  It is also easy to write this with Zend_Db_Select.  Alternately new `Zend_Db_Expr` might work for this.

```
   $select = $db->select()
   ->from('f', array('f.foo', 'f.bar', new Zend_Db_Expr('SELECT Sum(x) AS `y`
                                                         FROM   z AS pf
                                                         WHERE  pf.q_id = f.id') => 'f'))
   ->where(...);
```

Comment: i did the join way, forgot about zend_db_Expr